# Can I buy things at Duty free Dubai in the transit area of the airport and Check in a new baggage?

Tags: transit, luggage, dubai, check-in, duty-free

I have a transit for 11 hours at Dubai Airport and I wish to stay in the transit area of the airport and not pass immigration.

So I am curious if the duty free is in the airports transit area and once I buy a lot of luggage, can I check it in?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Get a new luggage and put all your shopping in that and go for boarding. They will stop you and ask for your bag to be put in checked luggage and you may well have to pay for it.

Comment: what if I have a luggage allowance for that flight? I just need to add in a luggage to my check in? I would still have to pay?